# ANTLR Distinguish DXF group codes and integers

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, dxf

I'm failry new to ANTLR and I'm trying to write a parser for [DXF files](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/) with ANTLRv4. DXF files use so called group codes to specify the type of the following data.

Example excerpt from some DXF file:

```
  0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ORTHOMODE
 70
     0
  9
  0
ENDSEC
```

For example the first `0` means that in the next line a String follows. The group code `70` means that an 16Bit Integer will follow, in the example it's a `0`.
My problem now is e.g. how can distinguish between the group code `0` and Integer `0`.
In the example snippet it seems that Integer values have some special indentation, but I couldn't find anything about this in the DXF reference.

My idea so far was following ANTLR grammar:

```
grammar SimpleDXF;

start       :   HEADER variable* ENDSEC ;
variable    :   varstart (groupcode NL value NL)+ ;
varstart    :   VAR ;
groupcode   :   INT ;
value       :   INT | ANYCHARSEQ ;

WS          :   [ \t]+ -> skip ;  
NL          :   '\r'? '\n' ;
HEADER      :   '0' NL 'SECTION' NL '2' NL 'HEADER' NL ;
ENDSEC      :   '0' NL 'ENDSEC' NL ;
VAR         :   '9' NL VARNAME NL ;
VARNAME     :   '$' LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* NL ;
INT         :   DIGIT+ NL ;
ANYCHARSEQ  :   ANYCHAR+ NL ;

fragment ANYCHAR    :   [\u0021-\u00FF] ;
fragment LETTER     :   [A-Za-z_] ;
fragment DIGIT      :   [0-9] ;
```

But obviously this fails when trying to parse the Integer `0`, since this is regarded as the group code `0` by the lexer, cause of the `header` rule.

So now I'm clueless how to resolve my problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

changed ANTLR grammar to include more lexer rules. Now the problem is that the lexer completely fails. The first input character is an `INT` token instead of a part of the `HEADER` token like I intended it to be... The reason for this is that removing whitespace with `-> skip` will not work if it's inside a single token (see following example):

For input `A B` (space between the two letters) the this grammar will work:

```
start   :   'A' 'B' ;
WS      :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

But this grammar will not work:

```
start   :   AB ;
AB      :   'A' 'B' ;
WS      :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by doing some preprocessing, where every group code and it's corresponding value are on the same line. The preprocessing also eliminates leading and trailing whitespaces as @UweAllner suggested. The example input file from the question after preprocessing looks like this:

```
0 SECTION
2 HEADER
9 $ORTHOMODE
70 0
0 ENDSEC
```

Like this its easily possible to distinguish group codes and simple integers, cause group codes are always at the start of a line, while integers are at the end of a line. The following example grammar solves the problem:

```
grammar SimpleDXF;

start           :   HEADER variable* ENDSEC ;
variable        :   varstart groupcodevalue+ ;
varstart        :   VAR ;
groupcodevalue  :   GROUPCODE value ;
value           :   (INT | ANYCHARSEQ) NL ;

NL              :   '\r'? '\n' ;
HEADER          :   '0 SECTION' NL '2 HEADER' NL ;
ENDSEC          :   '0 ENDSEC' NL ;
VAR             :   '9 ' VARNAME NL ;
GROUPCODE       :   INT ' ' ;
VARNAME         :   '$' LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)* ;
INT             :   '-'? DIGIT+ ;
ANYCHARSEQ      :   ANYCHAR+ ;

fragment ANYCHAR:   [\u0021-\u00FF] ;
fragment LETTER :   [A-Za-z_] ;
fragment DIGIT  :   [0-9] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a rule like

```
group: groupcode NL value;
```

Otherwise (as you say) no distinction is possible between groupcodes and values as such.
Or, if one groupcode may be followed by several values:

```
group: groupcode (NL value)+;
```

And you should define header and endsec as HEADER and ENDSEC to allow the lexer to distinguish between "just a number" and "is the start of a sequence".
The same possibly for the start of the variable rule (and everything consisting of a fixed sentence).

EDIT:
Something like

```
HEADER      :   '0' WS* NL WS* 'SECTION' WS* NL WS* '2' WS* NL WS* 'HEADER' WS* NL ;
```

comes spontaneously to my mind, while not being very elegant. But strange file formats require exotic measures.

To straighten this out a little, would it be possible for you to trim the lines of leading and trailing whitespace before they are lexed and parsed?

Comment: I implicitly have this in the `variable` rule as a subrule: `(groupcode NL value NL)+` I also tried exchanging this subrule with your suggestion, but as expected I still get the same result...

Comment: The example you gave is indeed not parseable by this rule; with groupcode 70 and 0 as value consumed there stays a 0 between this and the presumed endsec consisting of 0 NL ENDSEC. Is there more than one value possible per groupcode?

Comment: There is only one value possible per group code, but a variable in the header section may have multiple parameters (group code + value). IMO the problem is that the value `0` is in the wrong token class because of the `header` rule, where the `'0' ...` causes the lexer to make a token for zeros.

Comment: @Ibizarudi I gave it another try; see answer

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to come up with a solution with preprocessing the dxf file thanks to your latest edit.